# Datadog: How to get a user's user_id using Datadog python library?

Tags: python, datadog

I'd like to run through a list of Datadog users and change their role from Standard role to Read-only.

Both when I run:

```
api.User.get('some users email')
```

and

```
api.User.get_all()
```

The user_id of a user is not displayed and that is the parameter that I need in order to run my script which will run through and change 95 users role.

The only way I found to display a user's user_id, is by going in the UI to Organization settings -> Users -> select a specific user and then the URL displays `user_id=47f261a0-fff9-11ab-bccc-da7ad0904453`

Does anybody know a possibly api-related way to extract a user's user_id from Datadog?

Answer (score 0):

Their [user API docs](https://docs.datadoghq.com/api/latest/users/#list-all-users) show a filter parameter. You could try putting the email address in there and seeing if it matches the user you're looking for.

But you could always fetch all the users from the API and iterate through those looking for a matching email address.